# How can I redirect stdout to some visible display in a Windows Application?

Tags: c++, c, windows, user-interface, stdout

I have access to a third party library that does "good stuff."  It issues status and progress messages to stdout.  In a Console application I can see these messages just fine.  In a Windows application they just go to the bit bucket.

Is there a fairly simple way to redirect stdout and stderr to a text control or other visible place.  Ideally, this would not require any recompiles of the third party code.  It would just intercept the steams at a low level.  I'd like a solution where I just #include the header, call the initialization function and link the library as in...

```
#include "redirectStdFiles.h"

void function(args...)
{
  TextControl* text = new TextControl(args...);
  initializeRedirectLibrary(text, ...);

  printf("Message that will show up in the TextControl\n");
  std::cout << "Another message that also shows up in TextControl\n";
}
```

Even better would be if it used some interface that I could override so it is not tied to any particular GUI library.

```
class StdFilesRedirector
{
  public:
    writeStdout(std::string const& message) = 0;
    writeStderr(std::string const& errorMessage) = 0;
    readStdin(std::string &putReadStringHere) = 0;
};
```

Am I just dreaming?  Or does anyone know of something that can do something like this?

Edit after two answers:  I think using freopen to redirect the files is a good first step.  For a complete solution there would need to be a new thread created to read the file and display the output.  For debugging, doing a 'tail -f' in a cygwin shell window would be enough.  For a more polished application... Which is what I want to write... there would be some extra work to create the thread, etc.

Comment: `AllocConsole` is the missing piece. It produces the familiar console window. The read and write functions are awkward, but you can redirect stdout/stdin to/from it quite easily using this method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15547699/133836

Answer (score 19):

You need to create pipe (with [CreatePipe()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365152(VS.85).aspx)), then attach stdout to it's write end with [SetStdHandle()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686244(VS.85).aspx), then you can read from pipe's read end with [ReadFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467(VS.85).aspx) and put text you get from there anywhere you like.

Answer (score 18):

You can redirect stdout, stderr and stdin using [freopen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/freopen.html).

From the above link:

```
/* freopen example: redirecting stdout */
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  freopen ("myfile.txt","w",stdout);
  printf ("This sentence is redirected to a file.");
  fclose (stdout);
  return 0;
}
```

You can also run your program via command prompt like so:

```
a.exe > stdout.txt 2> stderr.txt
```

Answer (score 16):

You're probably looking for something along those lines:

```
    #define OUT_BUFF_SIZE 512

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        printf("1: stdout\n");

        StdOutRedirect stdoutRedirect(512);
        stdoutRedirect.Start();
        printf("2: redirected stdout\n");
        stdoutRedirect.Stop();

        printf("3: stdout\n");

        stdoutRedirect.Start();
        printf("4: redirected stdout\n");
        stdoutRedirect.Stop();

        printf("5: stdout\n");

        char szBuffer[OUT_BUFF_SIZE];
        int nOutRead = stdoutRedirect.GetBuffer(szBuffer,OUT_BUFF_SIZE);
        if(nOutRead)
            printf("Redirected outputs: \n%s\n",szBuffer);

        return 0;
    }
```

This class will do it:

```
#include <windows.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <iostream>

#ifndef _USE_OLD_IOSTREAMS
using namespace std;
#endif

#define READ_FD 0
#define WRITE_FD 1

#define CHECK(a) if ((a)!= 0) return -1;

class StdOutRedirect
{
    public:
        StdOutRedirect(int bufferSize);
        ~StdOutRedirect();

        int Start();
        int Stop();
        int GetBuffer(char *buffer, int size);

    private:
        int fdStdOutPipe[2];
        int fdStdOut;
};

StdOutRedirect::~StdOutRedirect()
{
    _close(fdStdOut);
    _close(fdStdOutPipe[WRITE_FD]);
    _close(fdStdOutPipe[READ_FD]);
}
StdOutRedirect::StdOutRedirect(int bufferSize)
{
    if (_pipe(fdStdOutPipe, bufferSize, O_TEXT)!=0)
    {
        //treat error eventually
    }
    fdStdOut = _dup(_fileno(stdout));
}

int StdOutRedirect::Start()
{
    fflush( stdout );
    CHECK(_dup2(fdStdOutPipe[WRITE_FD], _fileno(stdout)));
    ios::sync_with_stdio();
    setvbuf( stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0 ); // absolutely needed
    return 0;
}

int StdOutRedirect::Stop()
{
    CHECK(_dup2(fdStdOut, _fileno(stdout)));
    ios::sync_with_stdio();
    return 0;
}

int StdOutRedirect::GetBuffer(char *buffer, int size)
{
    int nOutRead = _read(fdStdOutPipe[READ_FD], buffer, size);
    buffer[nOutRead] = '\0';
    return nOutRead;
}
```

Here's the result:

```
1: stdout
3: stdout
5: stdout
Redirected outputs:
2: redirected stdout
4: redirected stdout
```

Comment: Why keep calling `ios::sync_with_stdio(true)` with each `Start()` and `Stop()`?  Is there other code somewhere setting it to `false`?

Answer (score 7):

When you create a process using [CreateProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425.aspx) you can choose a `HANDLE` to which stdout and stderr are going to be written. This `HANDLE` can be a file to which you direct the output.

This will let you use the code without recompiling it. Just execute it and instead of using `system()` or whatnot, use `CreateProcess()`.

The HANDLE you give to `CreateProcess()` can also be that of a pipe you created, and then you can read from the pipe and do something else with the data.

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this with cout or cerr:

```
// open a file stream
ofstream out("filename");
// save cout's stream buffer
streambuf *sb = cout.rdbuf();
// point cout's stream buffer to that of the open file
cout.rdbuf(out.rdbuf());
// now you can print to file by writing to cout
cout << "Hello, world!";
// restore cout's buffer back
cout.rdbuf(sb);
```

Or, you can do that with a `std::stringstream` or some other class derived from `std::ostream`.

To redirect stdout, you'd need to reopen the file handle. [This thread](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=126564) has some ideas of this nature.

Comment: This won't help you redirect another (spawned) program's stdout to anywhere of your liking.

Comment: The question refers to a third-party library. He didn't mention the need for redirection of another process' output.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I'd do:

1. CreatePipe().
2. CreateProcess() with the handle from CreatePipe() used as stdout for the new process.
3. Create a timer or a thread that calls ReadFile() on that handle every now and then and puts the data read into a text-box or whatnot.

Answer (score 2):

Here we'll set a new entry point `consoleMain` that overrides your own one.

1. Determine the entry point of your application. In VisualStudio, select *Project Properties/Linker/Advanced/Entry Point*. Let us call it `defaultMain`.
2. Somewhere in your source code declare the original entry point (so we can chain to it) and the new entry point. Both must be declared `extern "C"` to prevent name mangling.

   ```
   extern "C"
   {
     int defaultMain (void);
     int consoleMain (void);
   }
   ```
3. Implement the entry point function.

   ```
   __declspec(noinline) int consoleMain (void)
   {
     // __debugbreak(); // Break into the program right at the entry point!
     AllocConsole();    // Create a new console
     freopen("CON", "w", stdout);
     freopen("CON", "w", stderr);
     freopen("CON", "r", stdin); // Note: "r", not "w".
     return defaultMain();
   }
   ```
4. Add your test code somewhere, *e.g.* in a button click action.

   ```
   fwprintf(stdout, L"This is a test to stdout\n");
   fwprintf(stderr, L"This is a test to stderr\n");
   cout<<"Enter an Integer Number Followed by ENTER to Continue" << endl;
   _flushall();
   int i = 0;
   int Result = wscanf( L"%d", &i);
   printf ("Read %d from console. Result = %d\n", i, Result);
   ```
5. Set `consoleMain` as the new entry point (*Project Properties/Linker/Advanced/Entry Point*).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the [gamedev](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=126564) link in the answer by greyfade, I was able to write and test this simple piece of code

```
AllocConsole();

*stdout = *_tfdopen(_open_osfhandle((intptr_t) GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), _O_WRONLY), _T("a"));
*stderr = *_tfdopen(_open_osfhandle((intptr_t) GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), _O_WRONLY), _T("a"));
*stdin = *_tfdopen(_open_osfhandle((intptr_t) GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), _O_WRONLY), _T("r"));


printf("A printf to stdout\n");
std::cout << "A << to std::cout\n";
std::cerr << "A << to std::cerr\n";
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;

std::cout << "value read from std::cin is " << input << std::endl;
```

It works and is adequate for debugging.  Getting the text into a more attractive GUI element would take a bit more work.