# how to output results from a c++ program ran in dos to an txt file

Tags: c++

here is what my .bat file looks like:

```
cd C:\cygnus\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\bin
g++ -g hello.cpp -o hello -lm
start hello.exe
```

I need the results of hello.exe written to text file. Can you help me ?

Comment: google ["piping"](http://www.lagmonster.org/docs/DOS7/pipes.html).  FYI, at one point in computer history, if you didn't know how to do this, you were excommunicated.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574543/writing-all-program-output-to-a-txt-file-in-c

Comment: Wow, one moment - you are running something in a cygwin folder and run it from a windows cmd.exe? Could it be that you're kind of missing the purpose of cygwin, or is that intentional?

Comment: I forgot to add the standard, "what have you tried?"

Answer (score 1):

`hello > output.txt 2>&1`

will catch both standard output (1) and standard error (2) and send them to output.txt.

A quick Google search on "batch file pipe results to text file" brings you to [this page](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_redirection.php).

Comment: <FLAME> A quick read would let you know that this question has been resolved 4 minutes before your answer.  </FLAME>

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows, install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), then the operation

```
hello > file.txt
```

should work (as posted in the comment)

Comment: -1 for turning someone's comment into your answer.  Not because it's wrong... but because it's wrong for you to do that.

Comment: Also, you don't need cygwin to do that, this one of the few things `cmd.exe` is capable of :)

Comment: thanks, how do you display the text file on the screen after clicking on the .bat file? this can save me an extra step

Comment: on ubuntu its something like cat file.txt (to display it in cmd, if i got you right), I don't know, if that works on windows, but with cygwin it should work

Comment: Also, it seems that cygwin is already installed, note the path in the first line ;)

Comment: @ Hulk... yeah, I recognized that too late :(

Comment: type file.txt didnt work.. I need that text file to automatically open up when i run the bat file

Comment: `start notepad "file.txt"` However, you've just scope creeped your question.

Comment: Question also asked (and answered) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657777/open-text-file-and-program-shortcut-in-windows-batch-file)

Comment: @Dan Andrews: I don't see a problem here considering the answer acknowledges the comment.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for letting me know that you don't see a problem with his actions.