# C - add print to file option at the end of a function

Tags: c, printf

say a I have a function with many printf statements and at the end of it I want to add an option to save the already printed items to a text file.

Ex:

```
void print_Items(float a, float b, float c){

printf("%f", a);
printf("%f", b);
printf("%f", c);

printf("s", "Press s to save above list to a file or q to quit");

ch = getchar();

switch (ch){

 case 's':
     PRINT TO FILE
     break;

 case 'q':
     break;

}
```

I want to avoid creating another similar function that just specifically generates and prints the same contents to a file

Comment: [idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/), also C is not C++, please don't spam tags.

Comment: They're gone, disappeared into stdout.  I suggest that you create a print function that takes an 'fd' parameter and then call it twice, once with stdout, then with whatver open file descriptor you wish.

Comment: thanks - C++ was auto suggested hence why I added

Comment: You can use `fprintf` to print. That way, same functions, just pass in the `stdout` or `file handle`

Comment: `printf("s", "Press s to save above list to a file or q to quit");` will just print "s"

Comment: thanks your directions helped me to research in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally all the print statements are pushed into a txt file through the command line using an example like :

test.exe > stdout.txt

**Take a look at this link**

[Writing ALL program output to a txt file in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574543/writing-all-program-output-to-a-txt-file-in-c)

freopen() should allow you to use the switch case to enable a debug of sorts and push all the print statements into a txt file.