# QtScript output redirection

Tags: c++, qt, qtscript

When I call this code:

```
QScriptEngine e;
e.evaluate("print('hello, world!')");
```

the output text (from print method) is written to main application's terminal.

Is there any way to redirect it to a custom QIODevice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace `print()` with your own implementation:

First, define a C++ function that does what you want. In this case, it's just empty for exposition:

```
QScriptValue myPrint( QScriptContext * ctx, QScriptEngine * eng ) {
    return QScriptValue();
}
```

Then install that function as your new `print()`:

```
QScriptEngine e = ...;
e.globalObject().setProperty( "print", e.newFunction( &myPrint ) );
e.evaluate( "print(21);" ); // prints nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

The output text goes to stdout, so you need to redirect stdout. For ideas see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573724/how-can-i-redirect-stdout-to-some-visible-display-in-a-windows-application). Best ideas: use reopen to redirect to a FILE*, or (better) use rdbuf to redirect stdout to some other stream derived from std::ostream, and you could play with QFile.open(1,...)-

Comment: There are a lots of texts, going to stdout (QWarnings, QDebug to stderr, other printf/scanf etc). I need to redirect only output of QScriptEngine...