# Console application to MFC application

Tags: c++, mfc

I was wondering if I coded a program in console mode then I want to `cout` everything in and MFC application, can I do that?

For example, if I had a program like

```
cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
```

Then I designed a MFC application, can I display "Hello World!" inside it?  For example, like `include` in PHP?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this what you want to do.. Launch the console application from the MFC app and display the console app's output in a text box (or similar control) in the MFC app? And I don't get the reference to PHP "include".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Visual Studio , you can run the console application in MFC, provided you have checked the MFC support option . This option appears when you create a new project.

EDIT

@Ashwin - one *can* use cout inside an MFC app - http://pastebin.com/dAwFCCWX

@MixedCoder - Heres what you need to do - http://tinypic.com/r/34jdclt/7

Comment: @Sujay Ghosh thnks i will test it :)

Comment: @Sujay Ghosh ummm idk how to do it :S can you tell me how like ummm project>proprites or something like that :(

Comment: @Sujay:How can you output cout in a MFC application. It's not about just changing the project property from console to MFC here.

Comment: @Sujay:Do you mean we can use "cout" in a class derived from CDialog?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. You cannot use cout in MFC App. if you want to output some value you will have to use for ex:
  MessageBox("Hello World", "App", MB_OK);.

Comment: but i will still be able to run my console program?
i mean i have coded a big prgram i can run it inside the MFC

Answer (score 0):

Using pipes would be the best option. Similar questions have been posted on this subject.
Please refer [How can I redirect stdout to some visible display in a Windows Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573724/how-can-i-redirect-stdout-to-some-visible-display-in-a-windows-application)

On the other hand, if you just want to create an MFC project, copy the code for the console app over to it, run it and expect to see the output in a window.. that would not work. You have to do some additional coding to achieve this.