# Redirecting function output to /dev/null

Tags: c++, stdout

I am using a library that is printing a warning message to `cout` or `cerr`. I don't want this warning message to reach the output of my program. How can I catch this output and put it into `/dev/null` or similar?

MWE:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "Boring message. " << std::endl;
};

int main()
{
    foo();
    std::cout << "Interesting message." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output should be:

```
Interesting message.
```

---

How should I modify `main` to get the desired output? (`foo` must not be changed.)

---

I tried using `freopen()` and `fclose(stdout)` as suggested in this question [How can I redirect stdout to some visible display in a Windows Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573724/how-can-i-redirect-stdout-to-some-visible-display-in-a-windows-application). The result is that nothing is printed.

Comment: `freopen` is definitely the best-practice to be applied in this case.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are sure that thing does not redirect output (e.g. to `/dev/tty/`, which would be standard-out again) (which I don't think), you could redirect before calling them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

void foobar() { std::cout << "foobar!\nfrob!!"; }

int main () {    
    using namespace std;

    streambuf *old = cout.rdbuf(); // <-- save        
    stringstream ss;

    cout.rdbuf (ss.rdbuf());       // <-- redirect
    foobar();                      // <-- call
    cout.rdbuf (old);              // <-- restore

    // test
    cout << "[[" << ss.str() << "]]" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 24):

May I suggest a hack?  Set a bad/fail bit on the relevant stream before use of a library function.

```
#include <iostream>

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "Boring message. " << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout.setstate(std::ios::failbit) ;
    foo();
    std::cout.clear() ;
    std::cout << "Interesting message." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this works, however, I've decided to mark the other answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks @Unapiedra.  Manners always appreciated :)

Comment: Might I suggest saving the current state through `rdstate` and then resetting it to that afterwards?  That's a little bit safer than clearing the stream's state.

Comment: @GuyGreer don't think that would be an issue for cout at least as if a fail or bad bit was set beforehand then it's not going to output anyway, and you'd probably want to clear that or find out why a bad bit was set. I wouldn't want to polish it up too much as it is a hack and there are other excellent answers to this question available

Answer (score 8):

Use ios::rdbuf:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "Boring message. " << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    ofstream file("/dev/null");

    //save cout stream buffer
    streambuf* strm_buffer = cout.rdbuf();

    // redirect cout to /dev/null
    cout.rdbuf(file.rdbuf());

    foo();

    // restore cout stream buffer
    cout.rdbuf (strm_buffer);

    std::cout << "Interesting message." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. You have to `#include <fstream>` and to prefix `std::` where needed, e.g. `std::ofstream` and others.