# Suppress cout output from pcl registration

Tags: c++, iostream, point-cloud-library

From this question: [Redirecting function output to /dev/null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246317/redirecting-function-output-to-dev-null) I have tried to employ the following code:

```
 std::ofstream catchPCLStream("/dev/null");
 std::streambuf *originalOutputBuffer = std::cout.rdbuf();
 std::cout.rdbuf(catchPCLStream.rdbuf());
 std::cerr.rdbuf(catchPCLStream.rdbuf());

 icp_.align(dataCloudTransformedByIcp_, icpInternalUpdatePose_);

 std::cout.rdbuf(originalOutputBuffer);
 std::cerr.rdbuf(originalOutputBuffer);
```

But I still get a huge amount of output from the registration library:

```
[pcl::IterativeClosestPoint::computeTransformation] Not enough correspondences found. Relax your threshold parameters.
```

Is there something different about this output that stops it from being caught by this? Is it not going to `cout` or `cerr`?

Comment: Have you tried `std::cout.rdbuf(0);` before calling your function?

Comment: The output still being shown on the console?

Comment: @0x499602D2 yes, very much so, its verbose and in red.

Comment: @KristerAndersson It continues to print. even with `std::cout.rdbuf(0/Null/nullptr)`

Comment: Is your program multithreaded?

Comment: Try doing the same with the stderr `std::cerr.rdbuf(0);`

Comment: @KristerAndersson I am redirecting both. It continues to print to the screen.

Comment: @0x499602D2 My program is not but it is possible that the printing by pcl could be?

Comment: @Ben That's what I'm suspicious about, yes.

Comment: @0x499602D2 perhaps pcl provides a method to suppress error output? Otherwise I have found where my particular thing prints, I could edit the source code, although i would absolutely prefer not to.

Comment: @0x499602D2 it looks like there is an option to disable output here: http://pixinsight.com/developer/pcl/doc/html/classpcl_1_1Exception.html#a5274e2316874e55665f93bf4c3de1416 but i am getting a cant find header when i include `pcl/Exception.h`

Comment: Check the folder for where you're including the files. Do you see `Exception.h` anywhere?

Comment: @0x499602D2 yeah i am looking, doesnt appear, im not sure where to find this file?

Comment: Actually now from grepping it doesnt look like `DisableConsoleOutput` appears anywhere in my pcl include files. Maybe it has been replaced? I also cant access the pcl website for some reason atm

Comment: @Ben Try `#include <pcl/io/io_exception.h>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55166/discussion-between-ben-and-0x499602d2).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Due to the multi-threaded nature of PCL, the standard pipe `cout` and `cerr` away wont work. Instead you need to use the in-built functions provided by PCL to turn off the console printing.

Using the command:

```
pcl::console::setVerbosityLevel(pcl::console::L_ALWAYS)
```

Will turn everything off. There are also other levels and more information can be found on the  `pcl::console` namespace page:

http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/a02895.html#a1c1202ab693383b98842cb4f72ae625c