# Silencing stdout/stderr

Tags: c++, c

What is a C equivalent to [this C++ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8246430/2052436) for **temporarily**  [silencing output to cout/cerr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8246317/2052436) and then **restoring** it?

How to silence and restore `stderr/stdout`?

(Need this to silence noise from 3rd party library that I am calling, and to restore after the call.)

Comment: Use `freopen()` to redirect them to `/dev/null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a terrible hack, but should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int
suppress_stdout(void)
{
    fflush(stdout);
    int fd = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
    freopen("/dev/null", "w", stdout);
    return fd;
}

void
restore_stdout(int fd)
{
    fflush(stdout);
    dup2(fd, fileno(stdout));
    close(fd);
}

int
main(void)
{
    puts("visible");
    int fd = suppress_stdout();
    puts("this is hidden");
    restore_stdout(fd);
    puts("visible");
}
```

Comment: why it's a hack? Ithink it's confirming to POSIX spec.. question what to do on a non-POSIX system.

Comment: Minor nitpick: Shouldn't it be `close(fd);` last in `restore_stdout`? I made a version of this that works on Posix and Windows [here](https://godbolt.org/z/zWo1vdTvc) - but for some reason it doesn't actually work on Godbolt...

Comment: Why `STDOUT_FILENO` in `suppress_stdout` while `fileno(stdout)` in `restore_stdout`?

Comment: @user2052436 No particular reason.  I believe either is correct, but there may be pedagogical reasons to prefer one over the other, so I thought I'd demonstrate both.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Excellent suggestion.  Will edit.

Comment: @Swift I call it a "hack" because manipulating the underlying file descriptors of any FILE * feels dirty.  I would hate to see this code in production, and would heartily curse its author.

Comment: afaik it  happen anyway in various daemons and shell-like programs. As well as magic that hsppens when the program uses fork(). Alot of this information now slips under the hood of frameworks... until programmer runs into an issue where a spawned subprocess had hijacjed a file or socket or closed a stream. If anything, we have to curse Unix DNA.

Comment: @TedLyngmo because permission was denied to open "/dev/null". I added error handling and  `perror()` calls to track it (which one always should do). First part works, but stdout forever becomes invalid. Not sure how program can fix that either, because required `freopen ("/dev/stdout", "a", stdout);`  also fails - only read the permission exists. I guess their busybox or whatever they use doesn't support that, the trick works in other environments: wandbox, onlinegdb.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Aha, that makes sense.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I tried your version, "visible 1" is printed normally but "visible 2" is not printed.

Comment: @ZehuiLin What compiler and what target OS are you using? I tested it on a Linux and a Windows machine.

Comment: @TedLyngmo "visible 2" was not printed on the page you provided. Then I compiled the codes on [ideone](https://ideone.com) and "visible 2" was still not printed. Finanly I tries the codes on my PC locally and they works well. There must be something special happening on online IDEs...

Comment: @ZehuiLin Yes. I mentioned that in the comment as well. It's hard to debug that issue but it works in normal settings.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#define NULL_DEVICE "NUL:"
#define TTY_DEVICE "COM1:"
#else
#define NULL_DEVICE "/dev/null"
#define TTY_DEVICE "/dev/tty"
#endif

int main() {
    printf("hello!\n");

    freopen(NULL_DEVICE, "w", stdout);
    freopen(NULL_DEVICE, "w", stderr);

    printf("you CAN'T see this stdout\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "you CAN'T see this stderr\n");

    freopen(TTY_DEVICE, "w", stdout);
    freopen(TTY_DEVICE, "w", stderr);

    printf("you CAN see this stdout\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "you CAN see this stderr\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Two questions: 1) how to set `stdout`/`stderr` back to normal?
2) is there an OS-agnostic solution, not Linux only?

Comment: That is not OS agnostic; it is duo-gnostic.

Comment: This only works if the original stdout was a tty.  That is a terrible assumption to make.

Comment: This only sets output back to "normal" if it was going to the tty to begin with, which is not guaranteed.