# Is there a way to redirect string output in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, ostream

I am currently working on a C++ project and I have some functions that output some information to the console using std::cout. I also have a test function that calls these functions to check if they are working correctly. However, I find the output from these functions to be distracting when running the test function, and I would like to know if there is a way to redirect the output from these functions to a file or suppress it altogether.

I tried using `rdbuff`, but that unfortunately redirected my output from my test function aswell.

Is there a way to redirect or suppress the output from these functions, without modifying them? I am looking for a solution that can be implemented in C++11 or later. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Eventually what I want printed out is something along the lines of:

`Test1 PASSED`

`TEST2 PASSED`

`TEST3 FAILED`

and so on...

Here is my code:

```
/**
 * @author Jakob B
 * @file main.cpp [Driver Code]
 * @note Driver code for lab4
 * 
 * @brief This assigment focuses on using basic operations in a heap such as:
 *   - Insertion
 *   - Deletion
 *   - Peeking
 * 
 * Those operations were implemented using a Shelter class that includes a struct for Pets 
 */

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <limits>
#include <utility>
#include <sstream>
#include <unistd.h>

#pragma message("[" __FILE__"] " "Last compiled on [" __DATE__ "] at [" __TIME__"]")

/**
 * @struct Pet
 *    - Defines the Pet object
 *    - Includes a constructor
 */
struct Pet {
    std::string name;
    int arrival;
    Pet(std::string name = "", int arrival = 0) : name(name), arrival(arrival) {} //Constructor
};

int const PAUSE = 1000000; //usleep const

/**
 * @class PetHeap
 *    - Defines the heap with appropriate methods
 */
class PetHeap {
  private:
    std::vector<Pet*> petHeap;
    void percolateUp(int index);
    void percolateDown(int index);
    void deleteMin();
    Pet* peekMin();

  public:
    PetHeap();
    bool destroyHeap();
    void insert(Pet* pet);
    void adoptOldestPet();
    int numPets();
    void displayPets();
    std::vector<Pet*> massInsertion();

    bool testDestroyHeap();
    bool testInsert(); 
    bool testAdoptOldestPet();
    bool testNumPets(); 
    bool testDisplayPets(); 
    bool testPercolateUp();
    bool testPercolateDown();
    bool testDeleteMin(); 
    bool testPeekMin();

    void runTests();
};

/** CONSTRUCTOR:
 * @name PetHeap::PetHeap()
 * @brief Initializes an empty vector for the Pet pointers
 */
PetHeap::PetHeap() {
  petHeap = std::vector<Pet*> ();
}

/** DESTRUCTOR:
 * @name PetHeap::~PetHeap()
 * @brief Handles memory
 */
bool PetHeap::destroyHeap() {
  while(!petHeap.empty()){
    Pet* value = petHeap[(int)petHeap.size()-1]; //Pet*
    petHeap.pop_back(); //resize
    delete value;
  }
  if(petHeap.empty()) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

/**
 * @name void PetHeap::percolateUp()
 * @brief Percolates up the element at the given index until the heap property is satisfied.
 * @param index The index of the element to be percolated up.
*/
void PetHeap::percolateUp(int index) {
  /**
   * Parent formula: (i-1)/2
   * 
   * Find parent and compare it to the array
  */
 int parent = (index-1)/2;
 if(index == 0 || petHeap[index] > petHeap[parent]) {
  return;
 }  
  //swap the values
  std::swap(petHeap[index], petHeap[parent]);
  percolateUp(parent);
}

/**
 * @name void PetHeap::insert()
 * @brief Inserts a new pet into the heap and maintains the heap property
 * @param pet The pet to be inserted
 */
void PetHeap::insert(Pet* pet) {
  /**
   * Insert into the array
   * Call percolateUp to maintain the heap
  */
 petHeap.push_back(pet);
 int index = petHeap.size() - 1; //track the index of the pet
 percolateUp((int)index);
}


/**
 * @name void PetHeap::percolateDown()
 * @brief Percolates down the pet heap from the given index to maintain the heap property
 * @param index The index from where to start percolating down
 */
void PetHeap::percolateDown(int index) {
  int leftChild = 2*index + 1;
  int rightChild = 2*index + 2;
  int largestNode = index;

  /** @note bad values*/
  if(index < 0 || index > petHeap.size()-1) {
    return;
  }

  /** @note no children and it's a leaf node*/
  if(leftChild > petHeap.size()-1 && rightChild > petHeap.size()-1) {
    return;
  }

  /** @note node has a left child and the value of the current node is greater*/
  if(rightChild >= petHeap.size()-1 && petHeap[index] >= petHeap[leftChild]) {
    return;
  }

  /** @note node has two children and the value of the current node is greater than both children*/
  if(petHeap[index] >= petHeap[leftChild] && petHeap[index] >= petHeap[rightChild]) {
    return;
  }

  /** @note recursive case*/
  if(petHeap[leftChild] > petHeap[index]) {
    largestNode = leftChild;
  }
  if(rightChild < petHeap.size()-1 && petHeap[rightChild] > petHeap[largestNode]) {
    largestNode = rightChild;
  }
  if(largestNode != index) {
    std::swap(petHeap[index], petHeap[largestNode]);
    percolateDown(largestNode);
  }
}

/**
 * @name void PetHeap::deleteMin()
 * @brief Deletes the minimum element from the heap.
 * If the heap is empty, does nothing. Otherwise, deletes the root element (minimum element)
 * from the heap and reorders the heap using percolateDown() to maintain the heap property.
 */
void PetHeap::deleteMin() {
  if(petHeap[0] == nullptr) {
    return;
  }
  int lastElementIndex = petHeap.size() - 1;
  Pet* lastElement = petHeap[lastElementIndex];
  std::swap(petHeap[0], petHeap[lastElementIndex]);
  //now the last element is petHeap[0] and the first element is petHeap[lastElementIndex]
  delete petHeap[lastElementIndex];
  petHeap.resize(petHeap.size()-1);
  percolateDown(0); //sort the heap using percolateDown()
}

/**
 * @name Pet* PetHeap::peekMin()
 * @brief Returns the minimum value of the heap without modifying the heap.
 * @return The minimum Pet object in the heap.
*/
Pet* PetHeap::peekMin() {
  Pet* firstElement = petHeap[0]; //first element
  return firstElement;
}

/**
 * @name void PetHeap::adoptOldestPet()
 * @brief Adopt the oldest pet in the shelter.
 * @return void
*/
void PetHeap::adoptOldestPet() {
  if(petHeap.empty()) {
    std::cout << "\n[Error: No Pets in the shelter]\n";
    return;
  }

  Pet* oldestPet = peekMin();
  std::cout << "\n[Pet adopted]:\n\n";
  std::cout << "[name]: " << oldestPet -> name << std::endl; 
  std::cout << "[arrival]: " << oldestPet -> arrival << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::flush;
  deleteMin();
  return;
}

/**
 * @name int PetHeap::numPets()
 * @brief Returns the number of pets in the PetHeap.
 * @return The number of pets in the PetHeap as an integer.
*/
int PetHeap::numPets() {
  std::cout << "\n[Number of Pets]: " << petHeap.size() << "\n\n";
  return petHeap.size();
}

/**
 * @name void PetHeap::displayPets() 
 * @brief Display all pets in the shelter
 */
void PetHeap::displayPets() {
  std::cout << "\n[Displaying Heap]:\n\n";
  if(petHeap.size() == 0) {
    std::cout << "[Heap is empty]\n";
  }
  for(Pet* iter : petHeap) {
    std::cout << "[name]: " << iter -> name << std::flush; //flush buffer
    std::cout << "\t[arrival]: "<< iter -> arrival << std::endl;
  }
  return;
}

/** @name getName()
 * @brief Prompts the user to enter a name
 * @param name passed by reference
 * @return std::string name
 */
std::string getName(std::string &name) {
  std::cout << "[Enter Name]: ";
  while (true) {
    try {
      std::cin >> name;
      if (std::cin.fail()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("[Invalid input. Please enter a valid name]");
      }
      return name;
    } catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
      std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
      std::cin.clear();
      std::cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
    }
  }
}

/** @name getArrival()
 * @brief Prompts the user to enter the arrival time
 * @param arrival passed by reference
 * @return (int) arrival
 */
int getArrival(int &arrival) {
  std::cout << "\n[Enter Arrival]: ";
  while (true) {
    try {
      std::cin >> arrival;
      if (std::cin.fail() || arrival < 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("[Invalid input. Please enter a positive integer]");
      }
      return arrival;
    } catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
      std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
      std::cin.clear();
      std::cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
      std::cout << "\n[Enter Arrival]: ";
    }
  }
}

/**
 * @name int getInput()
 * @brief gets the input for the switch statement
 * @return (int) input
 */
int getInput() {
  int const MIN = 1;
  int const MAX = 7;
  int choice = 0;
  std::cout << "\n[Enter]: ";
  
  while (true) {
    try {
      std::cin >> choice;
      if (std::cin.fail()) { //std::cin.fail() if the input is not an integer returns true
        /// @link https://cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/2957/
        
        std::cin.clear(); // clear error flags
        std::cin.ignore(10000, '\n'); // ignore up to 10000 characters or until a newline is encountered
        throw std::invalid_argument("[Invalid input]");
      }
      else if (choice < MIN || choice > MAX) {
        throw std::out_of_range("[Input out of range. Please enter an integer between 1 and 16]");
      }
      else {
        return choice;
      }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& error) {
      std::cout << error.what() << std::endl;
      std::cout << "[Re-enter]: ";
    }
  }
}

/** @name goodbye()
 * @brief The function prompts the user goodbye
 * @remark Handles UI
 * @return void-type
 */
void goodbye() {
  std::cout << "\nGoodbye!\n\n";
}

/**
 * @brief Destroys the heap and prints a message to the console
 * @param heap A reference to the `PetHeap` object to be destroyed.
 */
void isDestroyed(PetHeap &heap) {
  bool dead = false;
  bool retry = false;
  dead = heap.destroyHeap();
  if(dead) {
    std::cout << "\n[Heap Destroyed]\n";
    goodbye();
  } else {
    std::cout << "\n[Something went wrong]\n";
    retry = heap.destroyHeap(); //try again
      if(retry == false) {
        std::cout << "\n[Program is leaking memory!]\n";
        std::cout << "\n[Force Exiting with code 1]\n";
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

  }
}

/**
 * @name void menu()
 * @brief Prints the menu for the user
 */
void menu() {
  std::cout << "\n\n"
            << "[1]   Insert a Pet\n"
            << "[2]   Adopt a Pet\n"
            << "[3]   Number of Pets in the Heap\n"
            << "[4]   Display Heap\n"
            << "[5]   Run Tests\n"
            << "[6]   Exit\n";
  return;
}

/** @name printTitle()
 * @brief The function prints the title
 * @remark Handles UI
 * @return void-type
 */
void printTitle() {
  std::cout << "\n\n*** Welcome to the Heap assigment *** \n\n";
  std::cout << "Please select one of the following?\n";
}


/**
 * 
*/
std::vector<Pet*> PetHeap::massInsertion() {
  PetHeap heap;
  std::vector<std::string> namesInput = {"F", "G", "E", "A", "B", "K", "L", "Q", "T", "Y", "O", "M"}; //12
  std::vector<int> arrivalInput = {2, 6, 12, 3, 7, 18, 36, 6, 9, 11, 10, 29}; //12
  
  std::vector<Pet*> inputValues; //vector with Pet pointers
  inputValues.reserve(namesInput.size());

  for(int i = 0; i < namesInput.size(); i++) {
    inputValues.emplace_back(new Pet(namesInput[i], arrivalInput[i]));
  }
  
  return inputValues;
}

/**
 * 
*/
bool PetHeap::testDestroyHeap() {
  //test destroying a heap with pets
  std::vector<Pet*> pets = massInsertion();
  bool done = destroyHeap();

  std::cout << "TEST1 FINISHED\n" << std::flush;
  usleep(PAUSE);
  return done && petHeap.empty();
}

bool PetHeap::testInsert() {
  //inserting a single pet
  Pet* pet1 = new Pet("Fido", 3);
  insert(pet1);
  bool result1 = peekMin() == pet1 && petHeap.size() == 1;

  //inserting multiple pets
  std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> newPets = {{"Rufus", 6}, {"Buddy", 2}};
  for (auto pet : newPets) {
    Pet* newPet = new Pet(pet.first, pet.second);
    insert(newPet);
  }
  bool result2 = peekMin()->name == "Buddy" && petHeap.size() == 3;
  std::cout << "TEST2 FINISHED\n" << std::flush;
  usleep(PAUSE);
  return result1 && result2;
}

bool PetHeap::testAdoptOldestPet() {
  //adopting the oldest pet from a heap with pets
  std::vector<Pet*> pets = massInsertion();
  Pet* oldestPet = pets[0];
  bool result1 = false;
  if (!pets.empty()) {
    result1 = destroyHeap() && peekMin() != oldestPet && petHeap.size() == pets.size() - 1;
  }

  //adopting the oldest pet from an empty heap
  destroyHeap();
  adoptOldestPet();
  bool result2 = petHeap.empty();

  std::cout << "TEST3 FINISHED\n" << std::flush;
  usleep(PAUSE);
  return result1 && result2;
}

bool PetHeap::testNumPets() {
  //getting the number of pets in a heap with pets
  std::vector<Pet*> pets = massInsertion();
  bool result1 = false;
  if (!pets.empty()) {
    for (auto pet : pets) {
      insert(pet);
    }
    result1 = numPets() == pets.size();
  }

  //getting the number of pets in an empty heap
  destroyHeap();
  bool result2 = numPets() == 0;

  std::cout << "TEST4 FINISHED\n" << std::flush;
  usleep(PAUSE);
  return result1 && result2;
}

bool PetHeap::testDisplayPets() {
  //displaying the pets in a heap with pets
  std::vector<Pet*> pets = massInsertion();
  bool result1 = false;
  std::ostringstream oss; //declare oss block
  if (!pets.empty()) {
    for (auto pet : pets) {
      insert(pet);
    }
    displayPets();
    //fix oss
    result1 = oss.str() == "A(2) B(7) E(12) F(2) G(6) K(18) L(36) M(29) O(10) Q(6) T(9) Y(11) ";
  }

  //displaying the pets in an empty heap
  oss.str("");
  destroyHeap();
  displayPets();
  bool result2 = oss.str() == "";

  std::cout << "TEST5 FINISHED\n" << std::flush;
  usleep(PAUSE);
  return result1 && result2;
}

bool PetHeap::testPercolateUp() {
  std::vector<Pet*> inputValues = massInsertion();
  int index = inputValues.size() / 2;
  int parentIndex = (index - 1) / 2;

  //percolating up an element
  Pet* pet = new Pet("Fido", 5);
  petHeap[index] = pet;
  percolateUp(index);
  bool result1 = petHeap[parentIndex] == pet;

  //percolating up an element that's already at the root
  percolateUp(0);
  bool result2 = true;

  std::cout << "TEST6 FINISHED\n" << std::flush;
  usleep(PAUSE);
  return result1 && result2;
}

bool PetHeap::testPercolateDown() {
  std::vector<Pet*> inputValues = massInsertion();
  int index = 0;
  int leftChildIndex = 2 * index + 1;
  int rightChildIndex = 2 * index + 2;

  //percolating down an element
  Pet* pet = new Pet("Fido", 5);
  petHeap[index] = pet;
  percolateDown(index);
  bool result1 = petHeap[leftChildIndex] == pet;

  //percolating down an element that's already a leaf
  petHeap[leftChildIndex] = petHeap.back();
  petHeap.pop_back();
  percolateDown(leftChildIndex);
  bool result2 = true;

  std::cout << "TEST7 FINISHED\n" << std::flush;
  usleep(PAUSE);
  return result1 && result2;
}

bool PetHeap::testDeleteMin() {
  std::vector<Pet*> inputValues = massInsertion();

  //deleting the minimum element
  Pet* minPet = peekMin();
  deleteMin();
  bool result1 = peekMin() != minPet && petHeap.size() == inputValues.size() - 1;

  //deleting the minimum element from an empty heap
  destroyHeap();
  deleteMin();
  bool result2 = petHeap.empty();

  std::cout << "TEST8 FINISHED\n" << std::flush;
  usleep(PAUSE);
  return result1 && result2;
}

bool PetHeap::testPeekMin() {
  std::vector<Pet*> inputValues = massInsertion();

  //peeking at the minimum element
  Pet* minPet = peekMin();
  bool result1 = minPet != nullptr && minPet->arrival == 2;

  //peeking at the minimum element of an empty heap
  destroyHeap();
  Pet* emptyMinPet = peekMin();
  bool result2 = emptyMinPet == nullptr;

  std::cout << "TEST9 FINISHED\n" << std::flush;
  usleep(PAUSE);
  return result1 && result2;
}

/**
 * @name void runTests()
 * @brief Runs tests for all the functions
 */
void PetHeap::runTests() {
  std::vector<bool> testValues;

  std::cout << "\n*** RUNNING ALL TESTS ***\n\n" << std::flush;
  usleep(PAUSE);

  testValues.push_back(testDestroyHeap());
  testValues.push_back(testInsert()); 
  testValues.push_back(testAdoptOldestPet());
  testValues.push_back(testNumPets()); 
  testValues.push_back(testDisplayPets()); 
  testValues.push_back(testPercolateUp());
  testValues.push_back(testPercolateDown());
  testValues.push_back(testDeleteMin()); 
  testValues.push_back(testPeekMin());

  for(auto i = 0; i < testValues.size(); i++) {
    if(testValues[i] == true) {
      std::cout << "TEST " << i+1 << " PASSED ***";
    }else if(testValues[i] == false) {
      std::cout << "TEST " << i+1 << " FAILED ###";
    }
  }
}
/**
 * @brief Main function of the program
 * @return EXIT_SUCESS upon succesful execution
 */
int main() {
  PetHeap heap;
  std::string name = "";
  int arrival = 0;

  enum OP_ID {
    ID_1 = 1,
    ID_2,
    ID_3,
    ID_4,
    ID_5,
    ID_6,
  };
  printTitle();
  while(true) {
    menu();
      switch(getInput()) {
      case OP_ID::ID_1: {
        heap.insert(new Pet(getName(name), getArrival(arrival)));
        break;
      }
        
      case OP_ID::ID_2: {
        heap.adoptOldestPet();
        break;
      }
        
      case OP_ID::ID_3: {
        heap.numPets();
        break;
      }
        
      case OP_ID::ID_4: {
        heap.displayPets();
        break;
      }
        
      case OP_ID::ID_5: {
        heap.runTests();
        break;
      }
        
      case OP_ID::ID_6: {
        isDestroyed(heap);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        break;
      }
        
      default: {
        /** @note do nothing*/
      }
      }
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```

The code has some bugs and it's missing some documentation because I haven't finished the lab yet. I hope that doesn't present and issue but in case it does I am terribly sorry.

Comment: Why not have the test function redirect output using `rdbuf`, call the function, redirect it back again, then print its own report ("Test1 PASSED")?

Comment: This is why logging libraries exist.

Comment: You could make the test functions print to `std::cerr` instead of `std::cout` and then, if you are running UNIX, you can run your program in such a way that standard output gets redirected to `/dev/null`, but standard error does not get redirected.

Comment: @Beta As I mentioned I'm not really familiar with using rdbuf, I googled it and pasted the first example that came up to my code and worked with it. Could you give me an example how I would do that?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I am running LINUX(preinstalled on server), but my professor might be running something else. I am also pretty sure he would run the program with just `./`

Comment: @MilesBudnek: Yes, especially for debug output, but more generally it’s also why functions should report failure in caller-accessible channels rather than presuming that the user is interested in them directly.

Comment: ^That. This is a failure of the function design. All of your options after the fact will be rather hacky. The proper solution is to rewrite the function.

Comment: Why make this code platform dependent, if you could just be using standard library functionality? `constexpr auto PAUSE = std::chrono::seconds{1}; ... std::this_thread::sleep_for(PAUSE);`??? Btw: you are aware that running the test immediately runs into a failed debug assertion?

Comment: This is actually an example of why debugging/logging information should usually not be written to a hard-coded stream.  While it is possible to redirect output from `std::cout`, using `rdbuf()`, it often would be simpler for the caller if your logging function(s) allow the caller to choose `std::ostream` by reference (e.g. by passing it as an argument).  The functions should not need to care about *what* stream is used for logging (e.g. a string stream, a file, a tailored stream that discards all output to it, `std::cout`, `std::cerr`, etc) - that depends on needs of the caller.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8246536/128940) appears to be exactly what you're looking for. But if it works, don't let that dissuade you from learning more advanced approaches.

Comment: Maybe log by severity and just show the messages with the severity you pick.