# AllocConsole() not displaying cout

Tags: c++, dll

I have a DLL where I use AllocConsole() and cout to display data for debugging purposes.
It used to work fine but since I updated my compiler (Visual Studio 2012) to the latest the dll just shows the console but not the prints/couts.
I am out of idea's as to why this is happening.
Any idea's?

Part of my code

```
__declspec(dllexport) INT APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hDLL, DWORD Reason, LPVOID Reserved)
{
    switch(Reason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:    
        AllocConsole();

        DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hDLL);

        //
        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
        DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)pSend, MySend);
        if(DetourTransactionCommit() == NO_ERROR)
             cout << "[" << MySend << "] successfully detoured." << endl;
```

But nothing gets displayed.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I vaguely recall that you might need to redirect the stdout to the console. I might be wrong though (since you had your code working earlier):

```
AllocConsole();
freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
std::cout << "This works" << std::endl;
```

Comment: `freopen("CONIN$", "r", stdin);` also works as expected.

Comment: Since ``freopen`` is depecrated (for security issues), you should use ``freopen_s(&new_stdout, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);`` where ``new_stdout`` is a ``FILE`` pointer.

Comment: `freopen_s((FILE**)stdout, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);`

Comment: @AriSeyhun do you know of a sollution that also allows redirecting  output from command line  like : `myapp.exe > out.txt`  . All solutions I have found do not allow redirecting stdout and stderr from initial host console

Answer (score 40):

After allocating a new console via [`AllocConsole()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/allocconsole), you need to re-open the standard streams (`stdout`, `stderr`, `stdin`) before you can use them.

You can do so by using `freopen` (in newer versions of Visual Studio you need to use `freopen_s`)
Example:

```cpp
FILE *fDummy;
freopen_s(&fDummy, "CONIN$", "r", stdin);
freopen_s(&fDummy, "CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
freopen_s(&fDummy, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
```

If you want to use the deprecated `freopen` you can [disable the warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/c-runtime-library/security-features-in-the-crt?view=vs-2019) by `#define`ing `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`.

If you also want to use the wide-character streams (`std::wcout`, `std::wcerr`, etc...), you need to call [`SetStdHandle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setstdhandle) to set a new output handle for your process. You can get the required file handle for this by calling [`CreateFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) with `CONOUT$` / `CONIN$` as file name:

```cpp
HANDLE hConOut = CreateFile(_T("CONOUT$"), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, hConOut);
```

Additionally, if you tried to use one of the streams before re-opening them, they will have the [`std::ios_base::badbit`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/iostate/) and [`std::ios_base::failbit`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/iostate/)
 set in their `iostate`, so subsequent writes / reads will be ignored.
You can reset the stream state with [`.clear()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear), after which you can read/write from/to the stream again:

```cpp
std::cout.clear();
std::cin.clear();
```

Heres a full example of re-opening all the streams after `AllocConsole()`:

```cpp
void CreateConsole()
{
    if (!AllocConsole()) {
        // Add some error handling here.
        // You can call GetLastError() to get more info about the error.
        return;
    }

    // std::cout, std::clog, std::cerr, std::cin
    FILE* fDummy;
    freopen_s(&fDummy, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    freopen_s(&fDummy, "CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
    freopen_s(&fDummy, "CONIN$", "r", stdin);
    std::cout.clear();
    std::clog.clear();
    std::cerr.clear();
    std::cin.clear();

    // std::wcout, std::wclog, std::wcerr, std::wcin
    HANDLE hConOut = CreateFile(_T("CONOUT$"), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    HANDLE hConIn = CreateFile(_T("CONIN$"), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, hConOut);
    SetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE, hConOut);
    SetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE, hConIn);
    std::wcout.clear();
    std::wclog.clear();
    std::wcerr.clear();
    std::wcin.clear();
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to open two consoles and write different stuff to each of them?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah A process can be associated with [only one console](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/allocconsole), but you could of course create a child process that can then have it's own console (using a pipe or some other form of ipc to send messages from the parent process to the child console). Alternatively you could use [AttachConsole()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/attachconsole) and switch between different consoles, however you would still need child processes to create those consoles for you, because each process can only create one console.

Answer (score 8):

This works using vs2015 with the line `std::cout.clear()`

```
if (!AllocConsole())
    MessageBox(NULL, L"The console window was not created", NULL, MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);

FILE* fp;

freopen_s(&fp, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);

printf("Hello console on\n");

std::cout.clear();

std::cout << "Cout line one." << std::endl;

cout << "Cout line two." << std::endl;

MessageBox(NULL, (L"Pause to see console output."), (L"Pause Here"), MB_OK | MB_SYSTEMMODAL | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);

fclose(fp);

if (!FreeConsole())
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed to free the console!", NULL, MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
```