# Is there such event as "Closing console" in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, console

Is there any event like in C# "FormClosing" but in C++ as Console closing where I can execute some code before the Console close? (In my case, I'd like to create a directory with the input of the user before the console is closed completely).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My guess is that you want to get the Event when clicking the [X]

```
BOOL WINAPI HandlerRoutine( DWORD eventCode )
{
  switch( eventCode )
  {
      case CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT:
      // do your thing
      return FALSE;
      break;
   }

  return TRUE;
}
```

Is that what you're looking for?

You also need to enable the Handler:

```
int main()
{
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler( HandlerRoutine , TRUE );
    getch();
}
```

[More Info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/handlerroutine)

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. However, I'm quite new to WinAPI and I was wondering, how do I exactly call this function in my program?

Comment: So, I have to "do my thing (create directory)" in the field where you said `// do your thing` and I just call this in my main program `SetConsoleCtrlHandler();` and it will constantly be checking if the user clicked the [X], right?

Comment: the handler will catch the close event and perform your code specified in there then fully exit the program. In short yes.

Comment: I never realized that consoles had hooks like this. +1

Comment: Worth noting that there is a time limit for responding to CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT in your handler, if you exceed it - Windows will just kill your application (you have about 5 seconds IIRC). Also, the handler will be called from a different thread then your main program!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close the console, then you can use `FreeConsole();`

If you then further want to open the console again, you can use [`AllocConsole();`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15547699/2470818)

Comment: "I" don't want to close the console, it's up to the user, if he decides to close the console, then the input he has entered will be written on a file in the same folder. So, I need a way to find out when he closed the form and write the file before it closes.

Comment: Ohh sorry, misunderstood your question then!

Answer (score 0):

A closing console effectively kills your application.  In windows I'm unsure of the ability to trap this, but in linux you could trap the KILL signal?