# Console showing when running winapi program

Tags: c++, winapi

I recently switched from codeblocks to VC++.  When I made a basic window program in codeblocks with winapi I would have a console window in  the background that displayed things such as std::cout.  Now when I run the same program in visual c++ it only shows me the winapi window, and not the console.  So if I set it to cout << "click"  when ever I click, it doesn't show because theres no console.

Does anybody know how to fix this?  I don't know whether I need to insert a line, or change a setting.

UPDATE:

I have set up the following code to attach a console to my window and have it register cout, cin and err.

```
AllocConsole();
AttachConsole(GetCurrentProcessId());
freopen_s(&conin, "conin$", "r", stdin);
freopen_s(&conout, "conout$", "w", stdout);
freopen_s(&conout, "conout$", "w", stderr);
```

although when I build it, I get an error saying that &conin, &conout are undeclared.  I don't really know what this first parameter is supposed to be, even after reading it's "A pointer to the file pointer to be provided by the call.".  What am I supposed to put here?

Comment: Use `AllocConsole()` to add a console to your GUI program.

Comment: How come codeblocks did that automatically?

Comment: It doesn't work any differently in MSVC++.  Hard to guess what you are doing wrong if you talk both about C++ and Visual Basic.  But high odds that you are using the wrong project template to get started.  Use Win32 Console Application.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm guessing he's getting his terminology confused; I'll address this in my answer

Comment: There is no need to call `AttachConsole(GetCurrentProcessId());` when using `AllocConsole()`.  The calling process is already attached to the console it created for itself.  You use `AttachConsole()` to attach to an existing console that was created by another process.

Comment: `conin` and `conout` are undefined because they don't exist in your code.  The first parameter is an **output** parameter.  YOU provide your own `FILE*` variable to receive the result of the redirect, then you can use that `FILE*` to read/write from the stream specified in the last parameter as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you link a Windows executable, you have the option of determining a flag in the PE header that determines whether or not the executable represents a *console application* or a *Windows application*. The only thing this flag does is determine whether Windows creates a console for your program when you start it (and possibly also connect the standard handles to it; I don't know for sure, but the `AllocConsole()` docs imply so). Typical Windows programs don't use a console, so this is a good thing for them.

I don't know what project templates Code::Blocks provides by default, but Visual Studio provides both console application and Windows application templates, and which one you choose determines what this linker flag is set to. You should be able to change the flag with either IDE in its project preferences page. (The different project templates mainly give you different starting code and settings to work from, but they're by no means absolute measures of what you can write.)

If you used Code::Blocks without making a project (somehow; I don't use Code::Blocks) it's important to know that MinGW, which is likely to be the compiler that Code::Blocks comes with, produces console applications by default.

As Jonathan Potter's comment above explained, there's nothing special about the console; you can create consoles and use them on the fly in your program. See MSDN for details. If you do this, however, see Remy Lebeau's comment below as you need to tell stdio (and iostream, in the case of C++) about it. Likewise, a console program is free to create regular windows as it so chooses.

The last pitfall is that Microsoft's compiler actually distinguishes between `main)` for console applications and `WinMain()` for Windows applications. `WinMain()` was introduced because 16-bit Windows needed extra information at startup: the `hPrevInstance` and `lpCmdLine` arguments are deprecated, and the `hInstance` and `nCmdShow` arguments can be accessed through a variety of other means. That being said, I don't know how to get Microsoft's compilers to accept `main()` on a Windows application project and vice versa; you could probably get somewhere with some searching...

Also be careful when you refer to the components of Visual Studio: Visual C++ and Visual Basic are very different things.

Comment: Hmmm, when I take the same code I've been using and put it in a wind32 console project, I get two errors: unresolved externals and unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup

Comment: There is one important difference.  If you create a *Windows Applicaton* and then call `AllocConsole()` to give it a new console, `std::cout` is **not** hooked up to it automatically since it is initialized before `AllocConsole()` is called.  You have to [use `freopen()` to redirect `stdout`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15547699/65863) to the new console, then `std::cout` will work. Otherwise, you have to use `WriteConsole()` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau why doesn't that also require a `cout.sync_with_stdio()` as the code sample implies? something about Microsoft's implementation of iostream? Thanks for pointing that out, though; didn't know that and updated answer to point out

Comment: @23scurtu for your first question, what happens if you change your `WinMain()` to a `main()` and `hInstance` with `GetModuleHandle(NULL)`? that might be some other gotcha specific to MSVC that I didn't realize

Comment: @andlabs: [std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio): "For a standard stream str, synchronized with the C stream f, ... this means that the C++ and the C streams use the same buffer, and therefore, can be mixed freely... **By default, all eight standard C++ streams are synchronized with their respective C streams.**"  `freopen()` updates the C stream, so it has an immediate effect on the C++ stream if they are synced.

Comment: @RemyLebeau ah, didn't know that either; thanks again (you can tell I haven't used C++ in ages by now =P )

Comment: @andlabs I get a compile error saying I need hinstance and if I do only one it cant find main.

Comment: @23scurtu I'm saying to change both; I forgot if msvc's linker option changes what entry point it requires (MinGW works with either)

Comment: @andlabs when i change both it says I got too maany arguements for call

Comment: @23scurtu which call? please paste the full error message.

Comment: @andlab Error 32 error C2197: 'HINSTANCE (__cdecl *)(void)' : too many arguments for call c:\users\victor\desktop\c++ programs\vc++\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp 57 1 ConsoleApplication1

Comment: @andlabs Also, these flags your saying I should change in my answer;  where are they? because  I looked in my project properties>C++>compiler where Microsoft claims they are but I have no "compiler" in there area

Comment: @andlabs its `wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);` and `GetModuleHandle(NULL),`  (in CreatWindowEx)

Comment: If this is really about `GetModuleHandle()` then something's very wrong. Could you paste your whole code in the question?

Comment: `int WINAPI main(HINSTANCE GetModuleHandle(NULL),` This is wrong. `main()` is always either `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. Also in your `ShowWindow()` replace `nCmdShow` with `SW_SHOWDEFAULT`. If THAT works then it shows that Microsoft's C compiler does something different with that linker flag and I'll update my answer.

Comment: @andlab My Man! It works, thanks!  Now...  Why is this able to draw a window?  Because it my tutorial they used int WINAPI WinMain.  IF they're interchangable, why use winmain?

Comment: Updated. Did you figure out what you needed for `freopen()`? I don't know if you can use `freopen_s()` in this case (or why it was introduced...)

Answer (score 0):

I run into similar issue recently. This solution worked for me:

```
FILE* conin = stdin;
FILE* conout = stdout;
FILE* conerr = stderr;
AllocConsole();
AttachConsole(GetCurrentProcessId());
freopen_s(&conin, "CONIN$", "r", stdin);
freopen_s(&conout, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
freopen_s(&conerr, "CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
SetConsoleTitle(L"appconsole");
```