# Why printf not giving output in a windows form C++ application

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, c++-cli

I created a simple windows form application C++ project in MS VS 2010. Then I intent to print to console:

```
// FtoC.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace FtoC;

[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    printf (" printing to console"); 


    // Enabling Windows XP visual effects before any controls are created
    //Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    //Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 

    // Create the main window and run it
    //Application::Run(gcnew Form1());


    getch(); 
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see I have commented everything except my printf statement.

It compiles without any error, but no output is coming. Why it is so?

**I modified the code as shown below:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Wincon.h>
#include "Form1.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>


using namespace FtoC;

[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
  {

   BOOL chk = AllocConsole();
if(chk)
{
  freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
  printf (" printing to console"); 
}
  else

{
    throw new SomeException();
}
    getch(); 
    return 0;
}
```

But now I am getting lots of errors in wingdi.h file, such as:

```
Error   270 error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\wingdi.h  750 1   FtoC


Error   159 error C2065: 'MAX_PATH' : undeclared identifier C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\wingdi.h  683 1   FtoC
```

What went wrong ??

Comment: Because such an application does not have a console assigned. Google the Win32 "AllocConsole" function for more information.

Comment: @Christian.K Thanks , could you please give a sample code ? I googled but it looks like they are used in a very complex codes, which i am unable to understand.

Comment: [That](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15547699/21567), for example, doesn't look very complex...

Comment: possible duplicate of [AllocConsole() not displaying cout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543571/allocconsole-not-displaying-cout)

Comment: @namezero I used AllocConsole, but new errors started coming in, kindly see me modified code.

Comment: As for the new problem, if it's not already included in stdafx.h, try including windows.h before any other windows header

Comment: Why not create a managed console application (that happens to open forms) in the first place? It should just be a matter of changing the `/subsystem` parameter in the linker options.

Comment: I got an answer to this same question, where you did not.

The answer is here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43771278/how-do-i-write-to-the-commandprompt-from-windows-gui?noredirect=1#comment74734522_43771278)

Answer (score 2):

It will not show you any output because WinForm does not have a console attached to them. Now if you really want to use a console

```
BOOL chk = AllocConsole();
if(chk)
{
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    printf (" printing to console"); 
}
else
{
    throw new SomeException();
}
```

Ref [AllocConsole()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I suggest checking the return value of AllocConsole, and if it fails, print a mess- oh right. Uh, throw an exception?

Comment: @KABoissonneault as you suggested modified to check return value.

Comment: @deeiip I am still getting compilation errors, kindly see my modified code above.