# How do I write to the CommandPrompt from Windows GUI?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli

Operating Environment: Windows 7, Visual Studio 2010, CLR GUI.

So I've been given the unglorious task of enhancing a GUI application that is started from a command prompt.  Because it is. Because poor design decisions by previous implementers. Anyway, it launches one of several GUIs depending upon the input arguments.

I'd like to be able to print back to the same command prompt window if (when) the user types something that the code doesn't understand.

Here's what I've tried (none of which output anything):

```
int main( array<System::String^>^ args )
{
  Application::EnableVisualStyles();
  Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

  OutputDebugString("hello");
  Trace::WriteLine("hello");
  Debug::Trace::WriteLine("hello");
  Console::WriteLine("hello");
  std::cout << "hello";
  printf("hello");
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

**Update:** I don't want to use `AllocConsole()`, as that opens a new console that disappears along with all of the data when the application exits.  Similarly, a pop-up message box won't work.  I'm looking for a way to make the output persistent.

The only way I can get output from the application to date is via a message box (non-persistent) or opening a new console that disappears when the application exits (via `AllocConsole()` ).  And I'm running from a command prompt, not the debugger's "Play" button.

**Update**
Why the down-vote for not doing research? I spent a day trying to solve this, looking through dozens of posts trying to find a solution, and to date I've found others looking for the same answer, but not finding it. `AllocConsole()` or changing the project type is always the solution, but neither is a solution for me.

**Update** 
I added the "full code", which is the 2 statements.  THAT IS ALL THE CODE.  So simple.  I'm skipping the start of the GUI because I don't care about that right now, I just want it to print back to the console where the application was started.  The most basic HelloWorld.  If there are project settings I need to post, I don't know which ones would be relevant.  This is where I want to print to the console, before the GUI is ever up.  I can't show the GUI if there is an error in the user input.

Comment: Use Win32's `AllocConsole` function to create a console window owned by your process which you can redirect stdin/stdout to.

Comment: I can't pick what I'm using, I'm adding on to someone else's code.  I've used AllocConsole, but it creates a new console.  If you exit the application the information goes away.  I want it in the shell where I started it. 

This is my first foray into Visual Studio coding.  I can't wait to get back to Linux...

Comment: You should edit your question to make clear what you want.

Comment: Did you choose the right type of project when you created it? Shouldn't you choose "Win32 Console Application" instead of Managed C++ or C++/CLI? Also note, for things to be persistent you will need to call the executable file by hand on a command prompt; clicking on the Visual Studio Play button for each running will always close the console window!

Comment: @sergiol:  I don't get to pick the application type.  That's the problem.  I'm stuck with what I've been given, and as far as I can tell there is no way to wrestle stdout out from under the clutches of Microsoft.  I am testing by calling from the command prompt, and I can't get anything to print back to that console.  I'm not trying to get it to print to the "Output" window of the IDE - I couldn't care less about that.

Comment: 1. you obviously are not showing the code that you would be modifying that launches your C++/CLI Winform app 2. if you don't launch this from the command line or don't set a breakpoint, you won't see anything show up.

Comment: @crashmstr see my added comments - I don't want to show the form, I want to print text instead of showing the form because the user made a mistake and I want to inform the user of the mistake.  And I am launching this from the command line, and nothing is showing up.

Comment: @PfunnyGuy the reason I asked for more code was that other people were just seeing a console app (and not existing code that you were trying to change). See my answer I've just added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the project, select Properties
Under Linker -> System, Change Subsystem from Windows to Console.

A Windows subsystem application cannot write to console, but by changing the subsystem to Console (which can write to the calling console), the Form part of the application can still work (tested in Visual Studio 2010).