# Unable to write to AllocConsole()

Tags: c++, console, dll-injection

I have a cpp dll in which I want to print text to console after injection. I used AllocConsole() to create console since its the easiest way, but I can't write in console.

When I try printf() nothing happens. Also I tried std::cout<<""; but no result as well.

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        AllocConsole();
        printf("Injected");
        CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)main, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: To write to a Windows console you need to use the Win32 Console API.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AllocConsole() not displaying cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543571/allocconsole-not-displaying-cout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After allocating a new console via [`AllocConsole()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/allocconsole), you need to re-open the standard streams (`stdout`, `stderr`, `stdin`) before you can use them.

You can do so by using `freopen` (in newer versions of Visual Studio you need to use `freopen_s`)
Example:

```cpp
FILE *fDummy;
freopen_s(&fDummy, "CONIN$", "r", stdin);
freopen_s(&fDummy, "CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
freopen_s(&fDummy, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
```

If you want to use the deprecated `freopen` you can [disable the warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/c-runtime-library/security-features-in-the-crt?view=vs-2019) by `#define`ing `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`.

If you also want to use the wide-character streams (`std::wcout`, `std::wcerr`, etc...), you need to call [`SetStdHandle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setstdhandle) to set a new output handle for your process. You can get the required file handle for this by calling [`CreateFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) with `CONOUT$` / `CONIN$` as file name:

```cpp
HANDLE hConOut = CreateFile(_T("CONOUT$"), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, hConOut);
```

Additionally, if you tried to use one of the streams before re-opening them, they will have the [`std::ios_base::badbit`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/iostate/) and [`std::ios_base::failbit`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/iostate/)
 set in their `iostate`, so subsequent writes / reads will be ignored.
You can reset the stream state with [`.clear()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear), after which you can read/write from/to the stream again:

```cpp
std::cout.clear();
std::cin.clear();
```

Heres a full example of re-opening all the streams after `AllocConsole()`:

```cpp
void CreateConsole()
{
    if (!AllocConsole()) {
        // Add some error handling here.
        // You can call GetLastError() to get more info about the error.
        return;
    }

    // std::cout, std::clog, std::cerr, std::cin
    FILE* fDummy;
    freopen_s(&fDummy, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    freopen_s(&fDummy, "CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
    freopen_s(&fDummy, "CONIN$", "r", stdin);
    std::cout.clear();
    std::clog.clear();
    std::cerr.clear();
    std::cin.clear();

    // std::wcout, std::wclog, std::wcerr, std::wcin
    HANDLE hConOut = CreateFile(_T("CONOUT$"), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    HANDLE hConIn = CreateFile(_T("CONIN$"), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, hConOut);
    SetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE, hConOut);
    SetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE, hConIn);
    std::wcout.clear();
    std::wclog.clear();
    std::wcerr.clear();
    std::wcin.clear();
}
```