# Showing debug console in c# WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging

for a current project i would like to implement a "developer-mode" that can be triggered with some kind of code or whatever.
The purpose of this mode would be to show the debug console, while the app is running. The user can then recreate whatever action caused an error and take a look into the console to see the error message.
I got some console to show using this code:

```
    private void DebugModeClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AllocConsole();
    }
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool AllocConsole();
```

But when i purposely threw an error message using another button like this:

```
    private void errorBtnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        object obj = null;
        obj.ToString();
    }
```

No error would show up.
My guess is, that this is not the debug console. But then: How do i do exactly this, using the debug console?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read this - C++ but the same kind of thing I think... https://stackoverflow.com/a/57241985/2393949.  Might give you some ideas at least!

Answer (score -1):

Simply saying `obj.ToString()` won't print out anything... you need to use something like `Console.WriteLine($"my obj: {obj}");`

I am not sure why you need to use `AllocConsole`. In fact, if you are working on Visual Studio, simply go to your project properties->Application->Output type, change from "Windows Application" to "Console Application" will allow you do `Console.WriteLine("hello");` on the console.

Comment: Yes, i am working on Visual Studio. This program will be used by a small company, who asked me for a program to manage their projects with. If they encounter a bug, they can simply call me and i would tell them how to open the "developers-mode". Then they can recreate whatever caused the bug and tell me the error message that popped up in the console. I can then go into my code and fix it. So: i don't want to use "Console.WriteLine", as i dont know what error could occur. And making the whole thing console-based is not the solution either, as they need a GUI.

Comment: OK now we know what exactly you want to do. Instead of asking your user to switching on a console mode and try to re-create the bug (if they could re-create it), how about keeping a log file? You can tell your customer to send you the log file, or even have a "send error report" button in your UI?

Comment: Oh my, thanks a lot. Thats actually a great idea. Do you have any knowledge on implementing such log-file system?

Comment: You don't have to implement it, there are existing ones. You can read about log4net https://logging.apache.org/log4net/, it's easy to set up, has different levels (for detailed debugging or for critical-issue-only release), etc.