# Unable to print to console in C++

Tags: c++, cmd, printf, sdl-2

I've been having some trouble with printf, stdout & stderr.

I've seen the questions like this, with the issue being related to \n on here already, but I'm already ending my strings with \n to no avail.

I'm fairly certain that this is due to compiler settings, because printing on the default settings works fine. However, I can't use the default settings because I need to use a library (SDL2)

Here's my compile script:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main.exe -IC:/cppLibs/SDL2-2.0.14/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2/ -LC:/cppLibs/SDL2-2.0.14/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/ -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -mwindows -lm -ldinput8 -ldxguid -ldxerr8 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm -limm32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -lshell32 -lversion -luuid -static-libgcc
```

And here's the code that's not printing:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char* args[])
{
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    fprintf(stdout, "test\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

I've tried various variations of this, and cout doesn't do anything either

I'm on Windows 10, my compiler is mingw64 10.3.0 (g++), and I'm using Visual Studio Code as my IDE.

I'm new to StackOverflow, so if this is the wrong place to ask, or if I'm asking incorrectly, then I apologise

Comment: What if you simplify? Remove the SDL include and try again. Remove the setvbuf and try again. This is not meant to solve, just to diagnose.

Comment: @Yunnosch There's no change if I remove the "#include <SDL.h>", the "setvbuf", the "fflush", or if I use regular printf

Comment: `-mwindows` disables the console. Remove it to get it back.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat well that serves me right for copy-pasting compiler args off of google, I don't know how to mark your comment as an answer but that solved my problem, thanks!

Comment: [See documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setvbuf?view=msvc-160): `size -
Buffer size in bytes. Allowable range: 2 <= size <= INT_MAX (2147483647). Internally, the value supplied for size is rounded down to the nearest multiple of 2.` so your size value is invalid. Check return value and `errno`!

Comment: I've tried on Win10 and MSVC and it just works, so can't reproduce.

Comment: Linux + gcc also can't reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/oY96af14h

Comment: Skye. Thanks for doing my experiments and reporting. Happy to see that you got an answer. Your comment gives credit to @HolyBlackCat , well done. Now it would be very acceptable, even appreciated, if you create yourself an answer. (mentioning Holy again). I believe Holy won't mind, but otherwise (they might be itching to cross that 50k...) you could remove your answer and let theirs take the applause. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My issue was that I'd copied some compiler arguments off of google. One of them, "-mwindows" suppresses console output.

@HolyBlackCat found this, but left a comment rather than an answer, so I can't mark it as a solution. If Holy reposts their comment as an answer, I'll delete this, and give them the credit

Comment: I'm fine with you posting the answer.

Comment: Cheers for harmony! ;-)

Comment: IIRC `-mwindows` doesn't just suppress console output, it suppresses the entire console. But you can manually create a new console and attach `std::cout` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543571/allocconsole-not-displaying-cout.