# Windows Terminal Application

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, terminal, console

How does one make a C++ application targeting the new Windows Terminal instead of the traditional `conhost.exe` Console?

Traditionally, we'd do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543571/allocconsole-not-displaying-cout):

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int WINAPI wWinMain( HINSTANCE /*hInstance*/,
                     HINSTANCE /*hPrevInstance*/,
                     PWSTR /*pCmdLine*/,
                     int /*nCmdShow*/ )
{

    AllocConsole( );

    SetConsoleTitle( TEXT( "This is the tab name!" ) );

    freopen( "CONOUT$",
             "w",
             stdout );
    freopen( "CONIN$",
             "r",
             stdin );

    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;

    std::cin.get( );
}
```

[image: Traditional console]

But I'd like to produce the following, using C++:

[image]

Comment: If you want a *console* app, why are you creating a *gui* app? Console apps have a `main()` entry point. GUI apps have a `WinMain()` entry point.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `WinMain` isn't just used for GUI apps, it's the windows standard for executables. `main()` is wrapped anyway. I figured I would have more control over allocating the console to the new terminal if I didn't rely on the console subsystem.