# Is there a way to open a new terminal window with code in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, command-line, terminal

I have an application and I want it to somehow open a new command line window for input. Is there a way to do this with C++?

Comment: It's almost a guarantee that there is a way to do this in C++. Your first step is to decide which operating system you are using: Microsoft Windows, Mac OSx, Linux, BSD, or something else entirely, and figure out what is the right approach on whatever operatig system you are using. Depending on the operating system additional factors must be determined as well, i.e., on Linux there are multiple terminal programs that are in popular use.

Comment: It depends - do you mean opening a new shell or another console window?

Comment: Please provide more details.  You tagged Windows so do you mean a "DOS box" cmd.exe window?  Do you mean a text input window running in your own process?  Do you mean running a second application that you create that communicates with your main process?   A workflow / use case / description of what you are trying to accomplish would help.

Comment: I mean opening a new console window. I am using the Windows operating system.

Comment: ShellExecute() to run cmd.exe?  We need you to be more specific.  Also, answer by editing your question to add the missing details.

Comment: Ok, for windows you can either start a cmd.exe program if you want that, but if you want a new console attached to your process you need to call AllocConsole to make a new console window and then you can do something like `AllocConsole(); freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout); freopen("CONIN$", "r", stdin); std::cout << "This works" << std::endl;`  Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57241985/2193968  If this is what you were after then yours might be a duplicate of that question.

Comment: "Is there a way to open a new terminal window with code in C++?" - Of course there is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit (Mar 23)

As pointed out in the comment `system` is synchronous which will block the main process until the called sub-program finishes. Therefore, you would want to make it asynchronous by putting `&` in each shell command (as I edited below), and the main program could proceed concurrently together with your called sub-program.

However, it still depends on your use case anyway.

### Answer

I'm not sure what is your "application" in this case. However, for applications to interact with each other, usually we would need some kind of APIs (Application Programming Interface), so that what you have on another application (a new terminal as you said) could be properly used in the "main" application.

If your desired result is just to get another terminal opened, we just have to call it. But remember, every Operating System has its own way to open a terminal, so if you like to automate everything, we have to use `macros` to check to current OS of the user, here is a suggestion:

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
  #ifdef _WIN32
  std::system("start program.exe &");
  // program.exe is app you have built to get input.
  #endif

  #ifdef _WIN64
  std::system("start program.exe &");
  #endif

  #ifdef __APPLE__
  std::system("open program &");
  #endif

  #ifdef __linux__
  std::system("open program &");
  #endif


  // #ifdef and #endif are just like if - statement.
}
```

Every compiler has the `macros` like `_WIN32`-stands for windows 32bit, `_WIN64`-windows 64bit, and so on. Its pretty handy to use them.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note "system" is synchronous and so will wait until the invoked command finishes. Remember to put a  &  at the end of the invoked unix command in order to invoke it asynchronously.

Comment: Note that `system` is a security nightmare and should *never* be used.

Answer (score 2):

To open a terminal or any other process, you need to call it.

For example, I use ubuntu OS and for open terminal If I say `gnome-terminal`, it will open it as I run my program.

**This is that code:**

```
#include <cstdlib>

int  main()
{
    std::system("gnome-terminal");

    return 0;
}
```

**For windows, you should call your cmd process. means that instead of `gnome-terminal` you need to write `cmd` or your process name**