# Redirect stdout C file stream to buffer

Tags: c, windows, stdout

Is there any way to redirect *stdout* file stream (C stdout) to a buffer in Windows?

The only thing that worked for me was:

```
FILE *fp = freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
printf("Hello\n");
fclose(fp);
```

but I always have to read the file back in order to get the buffer content. Any way to directly redirect it to a memory buffer?

Comment: Does it have to be in C code? Else, just redirect with > when starting the program

Comment: Yes, in the code unfortunately.

Comment: I'd like to directly redirect stdout into a char array and not writing it to a file and then reading it into a char array.

Comment: I guess here you have an example http://stackoverflow.com/a/617158/2549281

Comment: You can replace all `printf`s by `myprintf` where `myprintf` would be a function similar to `fprintf` but writing output to a buffer. `myprintf` would essentially use [vsprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vsprintf/) to get the output into a char buffer and then to your memory buffer.

Comment: Assuming your output does not get too large, you might use setvbuf() to enable full buffering to a buffer guaranteed to be large enough to hold all your output. Be sure to never call fflush(). You might run into an implementation-defined maximal buffer size, though.

Comment: I eventually implemented @MichaelWalz solution. Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace all `printf`s by `myprintf` where `myprintf` would be a function similar to `fprintf` but writing output to a buffer. `myprintf` would essentially use vsprintf to get the output into a char buffer and then to your memory buffer.

Here is a very simple and naive implementation of the concept with no error checking just to give you an idea.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void myprintf(char *mybuffer, const char *format, ...)
{
  va_list args;
  va_start (args, format);

  char tempbuffer[100] ;
  vsprintf (tempbuffer, format, args);

  strcat(mybuffer, tempbuffer) ;
  va_end (args);
}

int main()
{
  char buffer[100] ;
  buffer[0] = 0 ;

  myprintf (buffer, "Hello world!\n") ;
  myprintf (buffer, "Hello %s %d", "world", 123) ;

  printf (buffer) ; 
  return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Not a clean solution, just a workaround. What if you link a 3PP library that uses `puts` or `prinf`? Will you refactor every printf in the library code?

Comment: @coterobarros hence the _"very simple and naive"_. Yes it's only a workaround but apparently it's good enough for the OP

Comment: you are right. sorry, I was looking for a general solution to the redirection problem

Comment: @coterobarros I'm afraid there isn't one.