# Trying to redirect stdout and stderr on Windows - _fileno(stdout) returning -2

Tags: c++, windows, pipe

This is my first question here!

I'm about to port some piece of fine working C++ code from UNIX to Windows, which redirects stdout and stderr to a custom GUI Component through pipes. I need it to display feedback from a third party library that only outputs messages to stdout on my GUI.

According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/617158 this should work. In fact the code from the link works as expected in a fresh command line application built with Visual Studio 2017. However in my existing GUI application the call to `_fileno(stdout)` as well as to `_fileno(stderr)` both return -2 instead of the expected values 1 and 2, so just nothing is happening. Hard coding 1 and 2 to the relevant functions doesn't make it working either.

So could anyone explain

- What return value -2 could exactly mean? (Googled a lot on that - no success)
- If if is even possible to achieve what I want on Windows for an application without a console?
- If it is possible, what are the relevant steps to get it working?

For your information, I gathered my main experience on programming until now on Linux and Mac OS, so this might be something obvious for experienced Windows guys. The GUI application is based on the JUCE framework, so I'm using an auto-generated Visual Studio project created by the JUCE tool Projucer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike Unix-type systems, in Windows a console application and a GUI application are two different things. GUI applications don't have the concept of stdin, stdout or stderr - they only know about windows, textboxes etc.

The [documentation for _fileno says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs6wbdhx.aspx):

> If stdout or stderr is not associated with an output stream (for
>   example, in a Windows application without a console window), the file
>   descriptor returned is -2.

So if you want to use stdout and stderr, you need to build your application as a console application (you can still use a GUI).

An alternative method is to carry on building the application as a GUI, but allocate a console by calling [AllocConsole()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/allocconsole) at the very start of your application (i.e. the first thing you do in `WinMain()`) and then associate the stdout and stderr files:

```
if(AllocConsole()){
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
}
```

Comment: How could I overlook the "Note" box in the _fileno documentation. Thank you for pointing me there. Is it needed to change something at buildtime to let the application be a console app capable of this or is it possible to add console IO at runtime with AllocConsole (and somehow hide the unneeded console window directly) to achieve what I want?

Comment: @PluginPenguin You can set the mode when creating a project; not sure how easy it is to change an existing project. Another option is to use `EDITBIN` which comes with at least some versions of Dev/Visual Studio to switch the mode (`/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` or `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`).

Comment: @PluginPenguin if your application is started as a console application (either built as one, or using EDITBIN as TripeHound describes above), then you already have stdout and stderr set up. If you call `AllocConsole`, you don't have to change the way it's built, but you'll need to reassign stdout and stderr in your code as shown in the answer, because they won't have been set during startup.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working with the AllocConsole approach @DodgyCodeException proposed. In the end I now call the following code in my GUI Component's constructor to launch a console and hide it right away so that the user is not confused by an empty console Window:

```
if(AllocConsole())
{ 
    freopen ("CONOUT$", "w", stdout); 
    freopen ("CONOUT$", "w", stderr); 
    ShowWindow (FindWindowA ("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL), false); 
}
```

This works well at runtime, e.g. this way it's not called until the corresponding GUI component is constructed. Furthermore this approach makes the code more reusable for me, as including it in further project does need nothing more than adding the source file instead of keeping the need of modifying the buildtime settings in mind.