# File descriptor of stderr does not equal 2

Tags: user-interface, winapi, console, posix

I have been working on a Windows GUI application which means by default it does not get the standard input/output/error handles. This GUI app is also a child process to another GUI app (rendering into an embedded window and the standard handles are used for unified logging). We have an assertion in existing code that is reused for the child process, the condition of which is that _fileno(stderr) == 2. This assert had of course failed when there was no standard handles at all, returning -2 just as the Microsoft documentation said it would. Needing these standard handles I called the AllocConsole() function to generate them before getting into this code. However with AllocConsole() the assert still fails because _fileno(stderr) is returning 4. Also _fileno(stdout) looks to be returning 3.

My understanding was that file descriptors are numbered, in the order they are created, starting from 0. At least that is the POSIX documentation for the same function, rather than for WIN32. At the very least it seems that the WIN32 functions are not POSIX compliant. This itself would not be surprising. But I also don't see anything in the Microsoft documentation to explain this deviation of behaviour. So if there is initially no standard handles why would generating them not give them the expected numbering, 0 (stdin) 1 (stdout) 2 (stderr)? And if the numbering of new files starts after the standard ones, should we not expect _fileno(stderr) == 5 rather than 4, since _fileno(stdin) would be 3 instead of _fileno(stdout) == 3?

FYI, I am not looking for a work around here. I have already swapped wWinMain with wmain and changed the project for the child process to be a console application. This way everything works as expected. I'm just looking for an explanation why the file numbering appears so wrong.

Comment: Are you [calling `freopen()` after `AllocConsole()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51822723/)? I don't think that will guarantee that `_fileno()` will return `0|1|2` for `stdin|out|err`, though. You may need to loosen up your `assert` to check for `_fileno(stderr) != -2` rather than `_fileno(stderr) == 2` on Windows.

Comment: Ah, yes. I was calling freopen on stdout and stderr. I guess that explains my second question.

Answer (score 1):

> So if there is initially no standard handles why would generating them
> not give them the expected numbering, 0 (stdin) 1 (stdout) 2 (stderr)?

According to [`AllocConsole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/allocconsole#remarks):

> `AllocConsole` initializes standard input, standard output, and
> standard error handles for the new console. The standard input handle
> is a handle to the console's input buffer, and the standard output and
> standard error handles are handles to the console's screen buffer. To
> retrieve these handles, use the [`GetStdHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle) function.

So there are standard handles after `AllocConsole`. The reason `_fileno` returns -2 is just *"**stdout** or **stderr** is not associated with an output stream"*.

> And if the numbering of new files starts after the standard ones,
> should we not expect _fileno(stderr) == 5 rather than 4, since
> _fileno(stdin) would be 3 instead of _fileno(stdout) == 3?

`freopen` will generate a new fd, that is, starting from 3, the reason for `_fileno(stderr)` = 4 may be that you did not reopen `stdin`. With all 3 to reopen:

```
if (AllocConsole()) {
    freopen("CONIN$", "r", stdin);
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
}
```

I will get 3, 4, 5 as expected.

It is recommended to use the handle returned in `GetStdHandle` directly instead of file descriptors.